# change the strings again and again with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html box like this

```
<div class="results">
 , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 
</div>
```

I want when the page get loaded, i get this div box :

```
<div class="results">
 , 
</div>
```

I mean every two `,` (`, ,`) get replaced with `,` and at last, if there where 2 `,` repeating after each other , they get changed to one (`,`) and at the end just one of them should be exist, nothing more.

Also,

the div can be like this :

```
<div class="results">
 , , , , hello , hi , one , two , three , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 
</div>
```

So i need this :

```
<div class="results">
hello , hi , one , two , three 
</div>
```

How can we do it with Jquery ?

Comment: I am tired of people trying to do everything with jquery when plain JS can do the job and better. If you are just beginner to web client-side programming, why can't somebody think of plain JS first? With new framework like angularjs, the use of Jquery more than needed will less and less be justified in future. My recommendation: Learn Javascript and learn it nicely. For example, you question can be solved by simple JS so why not use it? I wanted to answer it but your mention of Jquery was off-putting and I am sure there are many like me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a verbose script that can show you the basics of processing strings in javascript.
It can be written shorter, but this should clearly show you the steps taken.

```
<div class="results">
 , , , ,  ,  , one , two , three , , , , , , , , , , , , , , test , , , , , , , hi , , , , 
</div>
<div id="result">
</div>
<script>
$(function () { 
    var items = $(".results").text().split(","); // split the content of the "results" div into an array
    var result = []; //we'll put the results here

    items.forEach(function (item) { //for each of the items in the original string
        if (item.trim() != "") // if it's not empty after removing whitespace
        {
        result.push(item.trim()); //add it to the result array (and remove extra whitespace around it)
        }
    });

    if (result.length > 0) //if there was at least one item
    {
        $("#result").text(result.join(",")); //join the items into a string using a comma character as a separator and put it into the second div
    }
    else
    {
        $("#result").text(","); // there were no non-blank items, put single comma character into the second div, per your request
    }
});
</script>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/pJRTF/1/) is a demonstration as well.
This is a better approach than replacing strings as it handles any whitespace and removes leading / trailing commas

Comment: WOW ! thanks my friend . helped alot ♥

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this

```
while ($("div.results").html().indexOf(", ,") != -1) {
  $("div.results").html($("div.results").html().replace(", ,",","))
}
```

Comment: Thanks but , i think it doesn't work dear friend. can you fix it please ?

Comment: It works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7KkwY/)

Comment: Very thanks dear batu zet.